What is the faith the Ephesians were saved through (Eph 2:8)
I was recently reading the context around Ephesians 2:8 and noticed that Paul strongly associates the Ephesian's salvation to the past resurrection of Jesus Christ:

4 But God, being rich in mercy, because of the great love with which he loved us, 5 even when we were dead in our trespasses, made us alive together with Christ—by grace you have been saved— 6 and raised us up with him and seated us with him in the heavenly places in Christ Jesus, 7 so that in the coming ages he might show the immeasurable riches of his grace in kindness toward us in Christ Jesus. 8 For by grace you have been saved through faith. And this is not your own doing; it is the gift of God, 9 not a result of works, so that no one may boast. Ephesians 2:4-9 (ESV)

So given that the context of Eph 2:8 stretches back 2000 years to the resurrection of the Christ and that the phrase in verse 8 "this is not your own doing" may more accurately be translated as "not of your selves," what faith is being discussed here that Paul claims the Ephesians were saved through?
I see at least 3 options:

The faith may be the faithfulness of Jesus Christ for which reason God raised him from the dead (Phil 2:8)
The faith may be the gospel narrative itself established by the resurrection of Jesus Christ that the Ephesians had believed in.
The faith may refer to the active belief by the Ephesian disciple of Christ in the gospel narrative established by the resurrection of Jesus Christ... this seems less likely given the phrase (not of yourselves - you Ephesians).

Indeed Paul says, "from faith to faith" (Rom 1:17) and of course one could argue all three are necessary for the salvation of the Ephesians, philosophically speaking, but how can we tell what faith Paul is specifically referring to here in this context through which the Ephesians have been saved?

Just curious as to why a thoughtful answer is voted for, but not the thoughtful question that drew it out.  Is it because the question is just too simple and obvious to even be considered? Is there some doctrinal issue or mistake? Just curious.

I voted it up because it is of paramount importance. Salvation essentially requires believers to have faith (belief) in the faith that Jesus Christ maintained for humanity. If someones hope for salvation rests merely in the hope of being randomly "chosen" by God, (gifted belief), then their faith is misplaced. It is when someone sees what God did for them through Jesus Christ and places their faith in that/Him being their means of salvation that they are truly saved. Indeed whosoever believes in Him today. without attempting to add to what He completed for them (works), will have eternal life.

I don't understand why this question goes into detail about the Corinthians, in regard to Paul's letter to the Ephesians. I suppose the answer would be the same in regard to what Paul teaches to both churches, but the question seems oddly specific about the Corinthians.

@LarsH.. Thanks. I wrote this at 1am in the morning and my brain was scrambled.

@MarkVestal... that makes sense, thank you.

How vital it is to give the context of a single phrase being asked about! And how pertinent the three choices suggested as to what kind of faith the verse speaks of! Given that the context goes back to the resurrection of Christ, this answer opts for suggestion "1. The faith may be the faithfulness of Jesus Christ for which reason God raised him from the dead (Phil 2:8)"
However, a key hermeneutic text I would use to validate that choice (and which supports Philippians 2:8) is:

"But now the righteousness of God without the law is manifested, being
witnessed by the law and the prophets; even the righteousness of God
[which is] by faith of Jesus Christ unto all and upon all them that
believe: for there is no difference: for all have sinned, and come
short of the glory of God; being justified freely by his grace through
the redemption that is in Christ Jesus." Romans 3:21-24 A.V.

Modern Translations, however, write "...faith in Christ Jesus", not "...faith of Christ Jesus". Yet the Greek text is not contested. Manuscripts show the Greek for ‘of’, with none saying ‘in’. This is the accepted Greek text: δικαιοσύνη δὲ θεοῦ διὰ πίστεως Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ  The preposition is not ἐν, but δua. The case is genitive, so it cannot read ‘in’. 'Faith' is in the genitive, 'Jesus' is in the genitive, and 'Christ' is in the genitive. It is possessive; it is his faith. This means that the following old translations are correct:
Tyndale’s English translation of 1525 – The rightewesnes no dout which is good before God, commeth by the fayth of Jesus Christ’
The Great Bible of 1539 – ‘The ryghtewesnes of God, commeth by the fayth of Jesus Christ’
The Geneva Bible of 1560 – ‘(To wit,) the righteousnes of God commeth by the faith of Jesus Christ’
The Catholic Rheims Version of 1582, ‘And the justice of God by faith of Jesus Christ’
The King James of 1611, - ‘Even the righteousness of God which is by faith of Jesus Christ’
Young’s Literal Translation of 1898 – ‘and the righteousness of God [is] through the faith of Jesus Christ’
The Companion Bible of 1922 – ‘Even the righteousness of God [which is] by faith of Jesus Christ’
I labour the point of this verse saying it is the faith of Jesus Christ that is key in God's righteous, free gift of justification being bestowed on all who believe, as Paul wrote it and the verse in question, so we can see how Paul thought on the matter of what this faith is.
If Christ had not maintained faith in the promises of God when, here on Earth, he found himself in fashion as a man, he would not have gone through with the death on the cross he knew the Father was calling him to. Why, he likely would not even have got past the temptation of the devil who questioned whether God had called him his Son, at Jesus' baptism! Jesus had faith in hearing the voice from heaven, at his baptism, "This is my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased" - Matthew 3:17. His whole life on Earth showed him demonstrating perfect faith and obedience, as did his death. He kept faith in the prophetic promises that said he would be raised.
If Christ had not maintained such faith, there would have been no redemption for us sinners. If Christ had not been faithful even unto death on a cross, his blood would not have been shed and therefore there could have been no forgiveness for us.
This is the faith that all Christians are saved by - the faith of Jesus Christ.
That had to come first, only after which could there be any gospel good news for us to respond to. That had to come first, only after which could we be given the gift of faith to believe that gospel of Christ, and live lives of faith in the Son of God. It is all of God, for grace wrought righteousness through the faith of Jesus Christ. What an immense gift then results from the faith of Jesus Christ, with Christians being the undeserving beneficiaries!

Awesome!  That solidifies why mere faith in Him then grants the faith of Him to the believer..."from faith to faith" (Rom 1:17).  Galatians 2:16 "Knowing that a man is not justified by the works of the law, but by the faith of Jesus Christ, even we have believed in Jesus Christ, that we might be justified by the faith of Christ, and not by the works of the law: for by the works of the law shall no flesh be justified."  Thanks @Anne! +1

Anne, I see now that it is the gift of Christ's faith that the believer is gifted...not as in the initial "belief" itself of the believer. This would be why Paul told the Philippian jailer to "believe", as in the jailer had the ability to do so. Also why the writer of Hebrews states that without faith, it is impossible to please God...as the believer must do that on their own. The believer is then gifted the "faith of Christ" which was the requirement to please God. Christ pleased God, we believe in Christ, and we are then gifted that same faith requirement that only Christ could keep.

So the faith of Jesus Christ, does Christ receive His faith through the Holy Spirit, which he is given an immeasurable amount of it. If we are Christ's we share in the Holy Spirit and thus share in His faith because it's of the Holy Spirit. Would this explain faith to faith; there's faith of men and then faith of God. And since the Holy Spirit is a gift, the same faith which Christ has, would also be a gift.

@KatieRoseMüller  People may form their own conclusions based on my answer; I'm not responsible for that. But your comment raises several questions which merit being posted on Stack. As they lead on from the op's question, they need to be asked afresh. Comments are not for going into discussions. I do encourage you to post your questions to me as a new question to everyone - on the Stack Christianity site. Thanks.

Ann, I appreciate your thoughtful response. Thanks for bringing to memory a more neutral translation of Rom 3. Your argument seems to rest ultimately on grammar and you seem to imply that based on the grammar there is only one type of faith that could be meant here, but this too seems a bit ambiguous. The faith of Jesus Christ could refer to: 1) The faith Jesus possessed, 2) faith of Jesus could refer to the faith concerning Jesus which is very close to faith in Jesus or 3)  faith of Jesus could be faith from Jesus as in the system of faith Jesus established through his death & resurrection.

@Anne, why should I in context prefer that the genitive in this case indicates what the object is possessed by instead of indicating what the object is about, or instead of indicating where the object is from?

@Austin  All translations of Rom.3:22 ought to have “faith OF” because the text is undisputed. The grammar further confirms that it must read “faith of”. My argument is that this verse is crystal clear that it is the faith of Jesus Christ that Paul means, supporting my answer that #1 is his meaning in Eph.2:8 But I stuck to the remit of your Q going no further. I cannot go into the other possibilities as they do apply in certain cases, but for the purpose of answering your Q I believe it is #1.

Thanks, Ann. Just for the record this response doesn't help me to reduce the ambiguity present in Ephesians 2:8 but exports it to Rom 3:22 where the ambiguity remains but in a different form. It is still helpful in highlighting a related verse that I can further consider. Again I really  appreciate your overall responsiveness.

Op asks,

"what faith is being discussed here that Paul claims the Ephesians were saved through?"

We all know of the Faith of Jesus  Christ that was demonstrated when He believed His Father's word and demonstrated it through His obedience  to the cross.
I would say it is God the Father's Faith that is in conjunction with His transcendent Grace that is revealed in Ephesians 2:8
To help substantiate the reason I've come to this conclusion is I highlighted versus that talk about God the Father  and how all is out of Him  in the following verses.
We now get a glimpse in Ephesians of  God the Father of our Lord Jesus Christ.

Through the will of God
1:1


Blessed be the God and Father of our Lord Jesus Christ, who blesses us with every spiritual blessing among the celestials, in Christ, according as He chooses us in Him. 1:2


He chooses us in him.
1:3


Designating beforehand for the place of a son for Him
1:5


delight of His will
1:6


His grace
1:6


Riches of His grace
1:8


Making known to us the secret of His will 1:9


His delight
1:9


He purposed in Him
1:9


According to the purpose of the one Who it's operating all in accord with the council of His Will . 1:11


For the laud of His glory
1:12


For the laud  of His glory
1:15


That the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Father of  glory,  may be giving you a spirit of wisdom and in revelation in the realization of Him.  1:17


Expectation of His calling
1:18


Enjoyment of His allotment
1:18


Transcendent greatness of His power 1:19


In accord with the operation of the might of  His strength which is operative in the Christ
1:19


Rousing Him (Christ) from among the dead 1:20


Seating Him (Christ) at His right hand 1:20


Subjects all under His feet Christ) 1:22


Gives Him (Christ) as head over all, to the ecclesia which is  His body, the complement of the one completing the all in all
1:23


God, being rich in mercy
2:4


His vast love
2:4


He loves us ( we also being dead to the offenses and lusts)
2:4


Vivifies us together in Christ (in grace, are you saved!)
2:5


and rouses us together and seats among the celestial , in Christ Jesus 2:6


He should be displaying the transcendent riches of His
grace 2:7


In His kindness
2:7


For in grace, through faith, are you saved, and this is not out of you;  it is God's approach present, not of works, unless anyone should be boasting.
2:8-9


For His achievement are we, being created in Christ Jesus for good works,  which God makes ready beforehand. 2:10

I believe all this goes hand-in-hand with the prayer that Paul is praying for believers to be given a spirit of wisdom and revelation in the realization of Him....God the Father
All is out of Him  which includes    faith  since He  is the originator of everything.

+1  Interesting perspective. We don't often consider the Father's faithfulness when we think of faith. I think this answer is consistent with option two as the Father's faithfulness is ultimately what we are to have faith in. The faithfulness of the Father is firmly established or otherwise on full display in resurrection of our forerunner Jesus Christ from the grave.

They, just as everyone else living in the Ephesians 3:2 'age of grace', were/are saved by believing this (Paul's "my gospel") specifically:
1 Corinthians 15:1-4

Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand;
2 By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain.
3 For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures;
4 And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:

They believed that Christ died for the forgiveness of sins, was buried, but rose again on the third day.  Salvation came at the moment of having this faith in Christ (Eph 1:12-13).  They had faith in what He did on their behalf and of nothing (no works) of themselves.
Ephesians 1:12-13

That we should be to the praise of his glory, who first trusted in Christ.
13 In whom ye also trusted, after that ye heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation: in whom also after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy Spirit of promise,

Ephesians 4:30

And grieve not the holy Spirit of God, whereby ye are sealed unto the day of redemption.

This is the "simplicity" of salvation found in the "glorious gospel of Christ" that Paul speaks of to everyone.
2 Corinthians 4:3-4

But if our gospel be hid, it is hid to them that are lost:
4 In whom the god of this world hath blinded the minds of them which believe not, lest the light of the glorious gospel of Christ, who is the image of God, should shine unto them.

2 Corinthians 11:3

But I fear, lest by any means, as the serpent beguiled Eve through his subtilty, so your minds should be corrupted from the simplicity that is in Christ.

